# Whats the issue with NoSuchElementException on a scanner when run through ideone?

Tags: java, palindrome, nosuchelementexception

I get an NZEC on my scanner on line 12, I've read a few blogs and several questions on here the say that the issue is closing the stream, but I do not understand where that happens. This error only happens on ideone, it does not happen on netbeans.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int t;
    List<Integer> k = new ArrayList();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        //Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException happens on this line
        t = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
    } while (t < 0 || t > 1000000);

    do {
        k.add(Integer.parseInt(in.next()) + 1);
        t--;
    } while (t > 0);

    for (int num : k) {
        while (!isPrime(num)) {
            num++;
        }
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: You get a **N**on **Z**ero **E**xit **C**ode?? or what exactly is a NZEC? Obs: *posted* code (without `isPime`) is working on ideone, maybe it is missing the requested input (or wrong format) -  maybe a [mcve] would help to help

Comment: "is working" meaning that it is not throwing any exception, not sure what the expected results are